# "node name cannot contain namespace"

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

When I try to open a generated moveit_config (I also have an other question about this Issue on this forum) I get an error that says that a node name cannot contain a namespace. This is also said in the ROS wiki about nodes:

*name="nodename"
Node name. NOTE: name cannot contain a namespace. Use the ns attribute instead.*

The node name is `name="$(anon rviz)"`
This is generated in every moveit config I have seen, so I don't know why this is suddenly a problem.

I also don't understand what the ns attribute is I have to use instead...

Kind Regards,
Yannik

EDIT: this is the launch file what's causes the issue on my pc (it seems that it does work on other pc's)

```
<launch>

  <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="" />
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="gdb --ex run --args" />

  <arg name="config" default="false" />
  <arg unless="$(arg config)" name="command_args" value="" />
  <arg     if="$(arg config)" name="command_args" value="-d $(find epson_moveit_config)/launch/moveit.rviz" />
  
  <node name="$(anon rviz)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false"
    args="$(arg command_args)" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find epson_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135411/%22node-name-cannot-contain-namespace%22/) by [Yannik_K](https://answers.ros.org/users/9556/yannik_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-04**:
It doesn't look like that line is the one causing the problem. Can you add your full launch file to your question?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-04**:
If this works on other machines, it's likely an issue with your machine. You may be able to get more debugging information by running roslaunch with -v

**Comment by [Yannik_K](https://answers.ros.org/users/9556/yannik_k/) on 2014-03-04**:
I checked the information now several times but I'm not really getting smarter from it. But I guess it's hard to help solving a problem with a machine from a distance. I think it's just really strange that it gives an error about the namespace but my pc causes it, could it be something I added to the ./bashrc?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-05**:
Since you have working and non-working machines, I would compare the environment across both machines, and I would compare the output from roslaunch -v across machines. Feel free to add all of those to your question if you'd like a second set of eyes on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the error was caused by the fact that my key setup (when installing ROS) failed.

So after reintsalling my complete ROS hydro system, it suddenly worked. This is not an answer to the fact what caused the problem, but at my pc it solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Yannik_K](https://answers.ros.org/users/9556/yannik_k/) with karma: 30 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0